# Why some of the visible frequencies have weak intensity but others are strong in emission spectrum of hydrogen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy

In emission spectrum of hydrogen,some of the visible frequencies have weak intensity,others strong.Experimental observations depict that some transition are more favoured than others.Bohr’s model is unable to account for the intensity variation. I could not not understand why the intensity varies.Could you provide me with a intuitive explanation?

Comment: Are you talking about intensity of the different colour of lights that get formed ?

Comment: Yes,I am talking about the intensity of  different  lights that get formed.

Comment: As wavelength of light increases , frequency first increases and then decreases. It’s understanding is given by plancks law which is quite complicated to understand.

Comment: There must be a diagram in NCERT too regarding this.

Comment: It is just due to the Boltzmann population distribution for the hydrogen atom: at any given temperature, the higher energy levels are less populated than the lower energy levels, and emission intensities correlate directly with that.